# Access static variables between two .net websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, iis-7, web-config

I had a asp.net 4.0 website in a server. I have recently created a new website that was made using razor but .net 4.0, in the same server. Both websites are configured using IIS 7.0, have a common sql server database and use c#. Right now I am trying to access variables from the first website (made using asp.net) to the second website (made using razor). To be more specific, I would like to use the static variable`Context.User.Identity.Name`of the old website in my new website.

Is there any way using the IIS manager or by using web.config of both websites so that both websites could point towards the same static variables.

Comment: Maybe you can have them in the same application pool and then use the asp.net Application object?

Comment: when you say asp.net Application object are we talking about a different object? because I need to use`Context.User.Identity.Name`. The exact same variable of the Context class.

Comment: No, but this object: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_application.asp Maybe it is outdated

Comment: Why you want to use those static variables?

Comment: that is an asp tag. I can not use it as one of my applications is made using razor.
Is there anything similar in c#?

Comment: @Anders Lindén: basically I currently have the variable `Context.User.Identity.Name` being used in my old website. It was not made by me. Right now in my new website that i have made I need to access this variable of the old website.

Comment: Seems like the database is the easiest thing to use here

Comment: But the variable is not in the database. The problem is I MUST use this variable. I dont have a choice to select a different variable.